# Hibernate 6.5 unable to find custom sequence in h2 database v2+

Tags: hibernate, h2

I use a custom sequence:

```
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "sequence",
        strategy = "de.sist.SequenceGenerator",
        parameters = @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                name = "sequence_name",
                value = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE"
        )
)
```

This sequence exists in the embedded h2 database.

On startup hibernate throws an exception in `org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator#validateSequence` because the sequence is unknown.

I was able to fix that by using a custom H2 dialect:

```
    @Override
    public SequenceInformationExtractor getSequenceInformationExtractor() {
        return SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public String getQuerySequencesString() {
        return "select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES";
    }
```

but this looks like a hack to me. `org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect#H2Dialect(org.hibernate.dialect.DatabaseVersion)` explicitly sets the query string to `null`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator#validateSequence` validates that sequences are properly setup i.e. match the expectations of the Hibernate model.
If you have a schema validation error, you should try to figure out what is wrong there and make sure that the sequence on the database matches the expectations of Hibernate to avoid runtime issues.

Comment: HIbernat cannot validate the sequence because it cannot load the instance with the default code. The sequence does exist and when I instruct it to look there it validates it without issues.
The problem is not that the validation fails but that the sequence can't be found because of the incorrect (empty) query.

Comment: If you look into the code(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.1/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/H2Dialect.java#L151), you will notice that this can only be null if you use a very old version of H2, that according to the creators of H2 does not support sequences. My guess is, that you are overriding the dialect with a version that has no constructor that takes in a `DialectResolutionInfo`, so it defaults to version 0 because your subclass calls the `H2Dialect()` constructor and so runs into this situation.